# How to send text data over agi channel

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami, agi

I am trying out communication between two Java applications in asterisk. Now I need to share some text data between the two communicating channels in call. I have tried following Manager API commands Please help me out in sharing some string/message between two channels in a call.

I have tried following

```
SendTextCommand se= new SendTextCommand("");
            se.setText("Test_message");

ReceiveTextCommand re=new ReceiveTextCommand();
            re.setTimeout(10);
```

And also

```
SetVariableCommand se=new SetVariableCommand("text", "27");
            SetVarAction sv=new SetVarAction();
            sv.setVariable("text");
            sv.setValue("27");

            GetVarAction gv=new GetVarAction();
            gv.getVariable();
```

Please suggest me if any lines are to be added or any new Class can be used

Answer (score 1):

If you need share data between channels in SAME asterisk, you can use GLOBAL(variable) or SHARED(variable) construction.

If you need send some info to other asterisk, you can use SipAddHeader/Header or jabber or Send/ReceiveText via sip channel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, My requirement suites usage of Send text on one channel and receive text on other channel, so Please suggest me how can I use those methods in Java AGI. Please help me out by giving sample code for Send text and receive text as well.

Comment: I am sorry, consult you agi lib documentation. I am not able use any lib availible, i use perl/php.